# Database create or redirect

Tags: database, mysql, installation

I am working on a site ABC.com, I have only access to the root folder. I am planning to install wordpress. I need to somehow create a database without any cPanel.

or the second option that comes in my mind is if I can install wordpress in server A where I  have only access to the rootfolder only and use the database from another server B which I can fully control through cPanel. I have created a database on server B. but how to set it(probably through wp-config.php) so it can be accessed through domain.

third option is if I can create a site(DEF.com) on server B and the domain of site(ABC.com) at server A redirects here and masks the URL with ABC.com. I dont want to show DEF.com at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not having cPanel doesn't mean you can't create a database, but if you are trying to install WordPress on a server without a database server, that is your biggest problem. I would consider other hosting.

Your questions in order:

1. cPanel is a convenience. So are Plesk and other similar pieces of software.

   1. If you have PhpMyAdmin (or similar) you can create the database using that. It is very obvious how to do that once you log in and there are many tutorials online.
   2. If you have SSH access, you can [create the database from the command line](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html).
2. Yes, you can run the site and the database on different servers. Some hosts have you do this anyway, whether you realize it or not. Just provide the server address when you define `DB_HOST` in `wp-config.php`. Use the IP of the database server instead of `localhost`. Using the domain name may also work but use the IP if you can-- one less DNS lookup. ***The database server has to be configured to accept remote connections, however, and many hosts do not allow that.***
3. Your third option doesn't make sense to me. I imagine that that is possible, but would be DNS server configuration and off-topic here, but if you have a server you can use, why not just use it and do away with the domain redirecting and masking?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am working for a client who has this ad on domain at server A, and doesn't even now have the other information regarding domain, and the server B is my server, which I am using for myself and clients. I was not sure how to move his domain to a different server if doen't even know when and from whom he bought this domain. all He knows is this is the root folder pointed to by the domain.

Comment: I gave you options I can think of but this isn't really WordPress question. It is a client-lost-their-login-data question. I just had one of those myself. However you hack this it is going to cause trouble if that problem isn't solved.